# Nautilus window background goes black when using custom themes

Tags: nautilus, themes, nemo

I am facing a problem when using custom themes in ubuntu 14.04 unity interface, such as the mbuntu-y theme appearing in the screenshot attached, as you can see the background of nautilus window goes black sometimes when using custom themes, this does not happen when I use Ambiance or Radiance themes.. I have to switch the view to list view and then back to icon view to get the white background again, the same thing occurs when using the nemo file browser..

I haven't been lucky on my search for a solution, I only found this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/552075/background-of-nautilus-go-black

Please advice on the source of this problem, and on how to solve it..

Thanks in advance :)

Screenshot: http://i58.tinypic.com/35n1quw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fortunately, I have found this temporary workaround to solve the problem:

https://github.com/shimmerproject/Numix/issues/121

the workaround is to disable the overly scrollbars when using custom themes, this can be done with the following command:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```